# Managing Google Maps API keys

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

My application uses a large number of MapView screens and I'm trying to figure out how to manage the API key between the debug environment and production. Apparently, there is no way to change the debug application key in Eclipse so I must use a debug map API key in that environment. Conversely, there is no way to export a package for beta testing without a production application key so I must change the map API key in every view in order to create a working package.

My first idea was to do this:

All MapView.xml files have this:

```
android:apiKey="@string/googleMapsAPIKey"
```

And then in strings.xml I put this:

```
<string name="googleMapsPIKey">@string/debugGoogleMapsAPIKey</string>
<string name="debugGoogleMapsAPIKey">TheMagicKeyString</string>
```

If this worked, it would allow me to change a single line in strings.xml and all the MapViews would get updated in the rebuild. But it didn't work. I guess strings.xml can't make references into itself. Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I recommend a simpler approach that involves taking advantage of an unlikely, but more specific asset folder to house your debug key.  To set this up, create a file res/values/maps-apikey.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="maps_apikey">[productionApiKey]</string>
</resources>
```

Then each developer locally will add a file derived from this one in res/values-v1/maps-apikey.xml where their debug API key is provided.  At runtime, the Android system will favor the more specific version res/values-v1/maps-apikey.xml for all versions of Android (since all are at least on API level 1 or higher).

Source control systems like git and svn allow you to add an "ignore" file which directs the tools to ignore this res/values-v1/maps-apikey.xml file so that each developer does not accidentally commit it to the repository.  To do this for git, simply add a file res/.gitignore which contains only the line values-v1 then commit this file.

To release your software, simply delete the res/values-v1/maps-apikey.xml file before exporting a release.  The resulting APK will then reference the version in res/values/maps-apikey.xml which is your correct production key.

Comment: only want to comment, that  '-' is not a valid resource name character in `res/values/maps-apikey.xml`. Excelenet solution!

Comment: For completeness, to reference it in your `AndroidManifext.xml`, you can [this](https://gist.github.com/mgalgs/ea9f0a511c6a14e9fdbc).

Answer (score 3):

you are doing the right thing but not the right way I think. Declare your string in strings.xml like this :

```
<string name="googleMapsAPIKey">TheMagicKeyString</string>
<!-- You can add this at the end as comment to keep a copy of another key for instance, to exchange it between debug and production-->
```

Note that you didn't give the same name at your 2 strings... One is called debug and not the other.

Comment: Well, that's not too bad a way to do it. I think I'll use this approach until the Android/Google/Eclipse team comes up with more automation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using maven and the [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), with a res-overlay directory that is only used in the release configuration.

Consequently, I have a `res/values/google_api_key.xml` file containing the debug key and a `res-overlay-production/values/google_api_key.xml` file containing the production key, and the latter overrides the former in the production release.

I'm also using Eclipse ADT, but this doesn't know about the release configuration, so it's happy to see the debug key and I can use the Android XML editors to set up my map views.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good way to do it! With Sephy's correction it should work perfectly.

On top of that, if you want to switch keys automatically between the debug & release builds, you can have a look at this post I just wrote: http://blog.cuttleworks.com/2011/02/android-dev-prod-builds/. It helped me stop worrying about configuration when building for different environments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using maven-android-plugin and I'm using a sneaky token replacement mechanism to do this.

I'm using the "morseflash" sample, and added this to the maven-resources plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <delimiters>
        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
        <delimiter>&gt;08*&lt;</delimiter>
      </delimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resources plugin allows you to define weird delimiters for search/replace. The default delimiter is `${*}`, but I added `>*<` so it would match XML element content. (Actually I used `>08*<`; I'll explain why in a moment.)

Then, in my strings.xml, I wrote this:

```
<string name="googleMapsAPIKey">08DEBUGKEYABCDEFBLAHBLAHBLAH</string>
```

And defined a Maven property in the release profile, like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release is done with the maven release
    plugin -->
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>performRelease</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <DEBUGKEYABCDEFBLAHBLAHBLAH>&gt;08RELEASEKEYABCDEFBLAHBLAHBLAH&lt;</DEBUGKEYABCDEFBLAHBLAHBLAH>
    </properties>
    <-- ... -->
</profile>
```

That creates a Maven property named after the debug Maps key, whose value is the release debug key.

Unfortunately, Maven properties are not allowed to start with numbers. My debug key and my release key both started with `08Wfj...` So I used the delimiter `>08*<` and made sure to include `>08` in my replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String debugMapKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String releaseMapKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

String mapKey = BuildConfig.DEBUG ? debugMapKey : releaseMapKey;

MapView mv = new MapView(this, mapKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom debug keystore in Prefs window -> Android->Build.

Comment: Here's the info about that from the Android docs: "If necessary, you can change the location/name of the debug keystore/key or supply a custom debug keystore/key to use. However, any custom debug keystore/key must use the same keystore/key names and passwords as the default debug key (as described above). (To do so in Eclipse/ADT, go to Windows > Preferences > Android > Build"

Note that you can use a custom keystore but you have to use the same password as the default. That won't really help.

Answer (score 0):

In the google developer console you can create one key for multiple sha1 codes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881624/1433372